# double free or corruption error c++

Tags: c++

i have a code for a graphic engine, it need to draw wire frames and line drawings, i made some adjustments to te original code of mine and now i get the error double free or corruption, but before the code worked just fine, does annybody know what i'm doing wrong?

```
void Wireframe::Generate(list<eye_point> &points, list<line> &lines, const ini::Configuration &configuration)
{
    string buffer;
    stringstream out;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrFigures; i++)
    {
        figure = "Figure";
        out<<i;
        buffer = out.str();
        figure.append(buffer);
        out.str(string());
        cout<<"de figure heeft de naam "<<figure<<endl;
        Read_info(configuration);
        Generate_points(points, configuration);
        Generate_lines(lines, configuration);
    }
}
```

in read info he reads the info from the ini file

```
void Wireframe::Generate_points(list<eye_point> &points, const ini::Configuration &configuration){
    Matrix schaal = Scale(scale);
    Matrix translate = Translatie(center);
    Matrix xrotate = Rotate_x_as(rotatex);
    Matrix yrotate = Rotate_y_as(rotatey);
    Matrix zrotate = Rotate_z_as(rotatez);
    Matrix eyematrix = Eye_transformatie(eye);
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix = schaal * translate * xrotate  * yrotate * zrotate * eyematrix;
    if(type.compare("LineDrawing") == 0)
    {
        linedrawing_point(points, configuration, matrix);
    }
    else if(type.compare("Cube") == 0)
    {
        cube_point(points,matrix);
    }
}

void Wireframe::Generate_lines(list<line> &lines, const ini::Configuration &configuration){
    if(type.compare("LineDrawing") == 0)
    {
        linedrawing_lines(lines, configuration);
    }
    else if (type.compare("Cube") == 0)
    {
        cube_lines(lines);
    }
}
```

here he sees wha for line drawing he needs to do, were by line drawing works just fine, the error is in cube.

```
void Wireframe::cube_lines(list<line> &lines){
    getline(lines, 1, 5);
    getline(lines, 5, 3);
    getline(lines, 3, 7);
    getline(lines, 7, 1);
    getline(lines, 5, 2);
    getline(lines, 2, 8);
    getline(lines, 8, 3);
    getline(lines, 3, 5);
    getline(lines, 2, 6);
    getline(lines, 6, 4);
    getline(lines, 4, 8);
    getline(lines, 8, 2);
    getline(lines, 6, 1);
    getline(lines, 1, 7);
    getline(lines, 7, 4);
    getline(lines, 4, 6);
    getline(lines, 7, 3);
    getline(lines, 3, 8);
    getline(lines, 8, 4);
    getline(lines, 4, 7);
    getline(lines, 1, 6);
    getline(lines, 6, 2);
    getline(lines, 2, 5);
    getline(lines, 5, 1);
}



void Wireframe::cube_point(list<eye_point> &points, Matrix &matrix){
    getpoint(1, -1, -1, points, 1, matrix );
    getpoint(-1, 1, -1, points, 2, matrix );
    getpoint(1, 1, 1, points, 3, matrix );
    getpoint(-1, -1, 1, points, 4, matrix );
    getpoint(1, 1, -1, points, 5, matrix );
    getpoint(-1, -1, -1, points, 6, matrix );
    getpoint(1, -1, 1, points, 7, matrix );
    getpoint(-1, 1, 1, points, 1, matrix );
}

void Wireframe::projectie(Vector3D &vector_points, eye_point &point_element){
    point_element.z = vector_points.z;
    if(vector_points.z != 0)
    {
        point_element.x = vector_points.x / -vector_points.z;
        point_element.y = vector_points.y / -vector_points.z;
    }
    else
    {
        point_element.x = vector_points.x;
        point_element.y = vector_points.y;
    }

}

void Wireframe::getpoint(double x, double y, double z, list<eye_point> &points, int nummer, Matrix &matrix ){
    eye_point point_element;
    Vector3D vector_points = Vector3D::point(x, y, z);
    vector_points *=  matrix;
    point_element.figure = figure;
    point_element.punt = nummer;
    projectie(vector_points, point_element);
    points.push_back(point_element);
}

void Wireframe::getline(list<line> &lines, int lijn0, int lijn1){
    line line_element;
    line_element.lijn0 = lijn0;
    line_element.lijn1 = lijn1;
    line_element.figure = figure;
    line_element.linecolor = linecolor;
    lines.push_back(line_element);
}
```

Comment: Could you at least edit your question to include a stack trace or line number where the problem is occurring. That is a __lot__ of code to try and debug in a web browser......

Comment: Run your code under `valgrind` or a similar tool. (I bet the bug is in your `line` class, likely a [rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) violation.)

Comment: Actually, it could be in any class you pass to `push_back`. Most likely whatever class you were modifying. Make sure your copy constructor and assignment operator don't do a member-by-member copy if the destructor `free`'s pointers! (Otherwise, destroying the copy you created in `push_back` results in a double free.)

Comment: The code you posted uses containers mostly. Please check stack trace and see the detailed implementation in case using some shared pointer or something. If you free a pointer which is being used by multiple part of the software, make it null for safety!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you might want to try AppVerifier tool which is free and is designed to detect double free errors http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807121.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The code posted doesn't directly do any allocation or freeing, so it's not relevant to your bug.

It's likely that the objects you're putting into containers (`line` and `eye_point`) have a bug. For instance, missing an assignment operator or copy constructor could lead to all sorts of baffling behavior.